# Change a variable inside a function from another function, what's the best way?

Tags: javascript

Update:

Thanks for the answers and I know putting them in a bigger scope is a good solution. However, what if the two functions are loaded from different external JavaScript files but on the same page?

For instance, the handler of the left button is from `a.js` and the handler of the second button is from the `b.js` and `b.js` is even loaded later when some event triggers it?

---

I have a function and there's a variable in it. I want to update this variable from another question, what is the best way?

here is the code:

```js
$('#update').click(function(){
  // I want to change the "x" in the other function to a random number or anything else after clicking this.
})
$('#test').click(function(){
  var x = 1;
  a();
  function a(){
    alert(x);
  }
})


// It can be done via the global way, but is that a must approach?

$('#global_update').click(function(){
  window.y = Math.random();
})
$('#global_test').click(function(){
  window.y = window.y ? window.y : 1;
  a();
  function a(){
    alert(y);

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="test">alert</button>

<button id="update">update</button>

<hr>


<button id="global_test">alert (global)</button>

<button id="global_update">update (global)</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to pollute the global scope you can wrap both the functions inside an IIFE and declare the shared variabile in the IIFE scope.

```
(function(){
  var x;
  $('#global_update').click(function(){
    x = Math.random();
  })
  $('#global_test').click(function(){
    x = x ? x : 1;
    a();
    function a(){
      alert(x);

    }
  })
})();
```

To answer your questions regarding a scenario with two different js files, there's no way you can create a shared common scope between them, in this specific case you have to rely on the global scope.

You can define a sort of subscope of window before importing the scripts and refer to that subscope in the scripts.

```
<script>
  window.subScopeAB = {
    x: 0
  }
</script>
<script src="a.js"></script>
<script src="b.js"></script>
```

a.js

```
(function(){
  window.subScopeAB = window.subScopeAB || {};
  $('#global_update').click(function(){
    window.subScopeAB.x = Math.random();
  })
})();
```

b.js

```
(function(){
  window.subScopeAB = window.subScopeAB || {};
  $('#global_update').click(function(){
    window.subScopeAB.x = Math.random();
  })
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, Karim, I have updated my question. Would you please take a look?

Comment: I see. Thanks. Looks fair enough but I am still hoping to find some inspiring tips.

Comment: maybe the above solution could help you out

Comment: Thanks, after a long-term research, your way looks quite neat and cool.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a local variable in a different scope, and you really *shouldn't*, since that completely defeats the purpose of variable scopes. If you want to share state via a variable, it has to be in scope for both functions, but that doesn't mean it has to be global. Just define a new scope containing both event handlers, and define the variable in that scope:

```
(function () {

  var x;

  $('#update').click(function(){
    x = Math.random();
  })
  $('#test').click(function(){
    x || (x = Math.random());
    a();
    function a(){
      alert(x);
    }
  })
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, meagar, I have updated my question. Would you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the functions global, make the variable global instead

eg. (in pseudo-code..)

```
$(function() {
    var global_var;
    function f1 {
       // ...
    }

    function f2 {
       // ....
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Rawrplus, I have updated my question. Would you please take a look?